# How to install Terragrunt 0.19.x version on Mac book

Tags: macos, terraform, homebrew, terragrunt

How to Install terragrunt 0.19.x Version on Macbook?

I tried `brew install terragrunt` which is Downloading 0.18.x only.

Option1:

```
brew install terragrunt

touch: /usr/local/Homebrew/.git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
fatal: Unable to create '/usr/local/Homebrew/.git/index.lock': Permission denied
fatal: Unable to create '/usr/local/Homebrew/.git/index.lock': Permission denied
error: could not lock config file .git/config: Permission denied
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/terragrunt-0.18.3.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/rohithgundala/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/f494cc7ebcfadf5e2610048e6c9f937e0151ff46cf0c226d83118e6d8ba704cc--terragrunt-0.18.3.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring terragrunt-0.18.3.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/terragrunt/0.18.3: 3 files, 19.6MB
```

Option2:

```
# Install Terragrunt
RUN wget -q -O ${BIN_DIR}/terragrunt "https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/releases/download/v${TERRAGRUNT_VERSION}/terragrunt_linux _amd64" \
 && chmod +x ${BIN_DIR}/terragrunt
```

Output:

```
bin/terragrunt: cannot execute binary file
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `linux`? Are you using Linux or MacOS?

Comment: This would be better asked on a platform specific forum like https://apple.stackexchange.com/ or https://superuser.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found Answer for this.

```
wget -q -O /bin/terragrunt "https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/releases/download/v0.xx.x/terragrunt_linux_amd64"

chmod +x /bin/terragrunt

 terragrunt -v
```

Comment: This will not work and should not be the correct answer. A Linux AMD 64 executable is not compatible with the macOS ABI and should not be run there.

Answer (score 1):

Install Homebrew as described at https://brew.sh/.

Then run the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/cunymatthieu/tgenv.git /usr/local/Cellar/tgenv
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/tgenv/bin/* /usr/local/bin
tgenv install 0.19.31
tfenv use 0.19.31
```

tgenv is a version manager for Terragrunt. https://github.com/cunymatthieu/tgenv/blob/master/README.md

It's extremely handy when you need to use a specific version or multiple versions on the same machine.

tfenv is a related tool and does the same for the terraform command: https://github.com/tfutils/tfenv

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of Mac OS the kernel is Darwin and the above answer will not work with an error like:-

`zsh: exec format error`

Please confirm that by running command `uname -a` and download the file specific to that kernel "terragrunt_darwin_amd64" for whatever version you want.

So below should work :-

```
wget -q -O /bin/terragrunt "https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/releases/download/v0.xx.x/terragrunt_darwin_amd64"

chmod +x /bin/terragrunt

terragrunt -v
```